# Scraping instagram profile with python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to aggregate some data from every post on a given instagram profiles.

I mixed codes found [here](https://www.promptcloud.com/blog/how-to-scrape-instagram-data-using-python/) and [there](https://michaeljsanders.com/2017/05/12/scrapin-and-scrollin.html) and decided to go with selenium to load and scroll along the page and BeautifulSoup to parse the data.

Unfortunately, even though I'm loading the whole page with selenium, I can only access to the first twelve posts...

I've tried to parse the html at the end of full page loading or even between each scrolling, same result.

Here is my code, it's loading instagram usernames in the users.txt file, feel free to put your favorite account and try (it has to have more than 12 posts to see the behavior but not that much if you want it to be quick)..

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime



class Insta_Image_Links_Scraper:

    def getlinks(self, user, url):

        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get(url)
        lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        match=False
        while(match==False):
                lastCount = lenOfPage
                time.sleep(3)
                lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
                if lastCount==lenOfPage:
                        match=True

        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        body = soup.find('body')
        script = body.find('script')
        page_json = script.text.strip().replace('window._sharedData =', '').replace(';', '')

        data = json.loads(page_json)
        print ('Scraping posts for user ' + user+"...........")
        for post in data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']:
            timestamp = post['node']['taken_at_timestamp']
            likedby = post['node']['edge_liked_by']['count']
            comments = post['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count']
            isVideo = post['node']['is_video']

            print('Post on :',datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    def main(self):
        self.ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        self.ctx.check_hostname = False
        self.ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

        with open('users.txt') as f:
            self.content = f.readlines()
        self.content = [x.strip() for x in self.content]
        for user in self.content:
            self.getlinks(user,
                          'https://www.instagram.com/'
                          + user + '/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Insta_Image_Links_Scraper()
    obj.main()
```

It should output the timestamp of each post on a user profile, and not only the firsts post corresponding to what you would see without scrolling.

Thank you !